# Everytime I stop an EC2 instance, another one is created

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new to AWS, and I tried EC2 instances,

But now I want to stop all the instances, and everytime I stop one, another is created,

Is there a way to stop all EC2 instances forever because I have a $1 bill for this,

Comment: You have an autoscaling group somewhere that is restarting them.  You must remove that first.  Is this in an Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 3):

This is the behaviour of an autoscaling group. Everytime you stop it, its health check fails which is triggering the behaviour you're seeing.

The instance itself should have a tag of `aws:autoscaling:groupName` containing the autoscaling group name. Find this autoscaling group within the EC2 console and set the minimum, maximum and desired counts to 0.

**If** the autoscaling group was created outside of the EC2 console i.e. CloudFormation template or part of an ElasticBeanstalk deployment then you should ensure that you change these settings within their configuration not directly via the console.